# VirtualBox Ubuntu: "can't find in /etc/fstab" error when mounting new shared Windows Host folder

Tags: linux, ubuntu, terminal, mount

I have been able to successfully mount a shared folder between my VirtualBox Ubuntu instance (v17.10) and my Windows 7 Enterprise (host) using the following code in the Terminal:

```
$ mkdir ~/guest_shared

$ sudo mount -t vboxsf shared ~/guest_shared
```

Here, my host folder I want to share is C:\shared and the mount source folder is ~/guest_shared. In the settings for VirtualBox, I have set the shared folder to C:\shared. This worked just fine after booting up my VM for the first time and after installing Guest Additions. I am able to share files between the VM and my host computer.

I'm now trying to change the host folder I want shared.

I create a different folder on my Host that I want to share, go back into the VirtualBox Settings >> Shared Folders for my VM, deleted the old shared folder host path (C:\shared) and changed to the new host shared folder path. This new path is C:\Users\123456\Desktop\Shared

I re-typed my previous code as such in Terminal to try to link my ~/guest_shared folder on my VM with the new folder on my host:

```
$ sudo mount -t vboxsf shared ~/guest_shared
```

However I am getting the error "/home/osboxes/guest_shared: can't find in /etc/fstab".

I either have bad syntax or I am missing a step.

Comment: Why don't use the same command again?

Comment: Because I want to change the host folder that I want to share. I no longer want to share with C:/shared, I want to share with C:/Users/123456/Desktop/Shared and this is what is giving me the error. Thanks

Comment: The share name (`shared`) can be the same, it's independent from real path.

Comment: Oh, I see what you are saying. However, when I do that, I'm now getting "/home/osboxes/guest_shared: can't find in /etc/fstab". Any idea what might be causing this?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show what command you are doing and what error you are getting.  Also, please run the command ``grep shared /etc/fstab`` and post the output (*in your question*).  Do not clarify or extend your question in comments.

Comment: Ok, I've edited the original post.